# How to set date format using regex using jsoup java

Tags: java, regex, date, web-scraping, jsoup

I am scraping data from the website and the data stores in csv file. There is a td in which date is coming having format **'dd/m/yyyy'**. Now what I have to do that I have to print 1 whenever the date will come in that td. So, I tried it with the following code.

```
if (tdElements.text().matches("\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+")) {
                    sb.append("1");
                }
```

but its not working. By using 'matches' the actual date (18/5/2016) is also not working but it is working with contains. But, regex are also not working with 'contains' so kindly provide me solution that how can I resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (tdElements.text().matches("\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+")) {
   sb.append("1");
}
```

The above code suggests you're manipulating multiple `td`s at once.
The `text()` method will return the **combined** text of the `td`s.
This is why the `matches` method finds nothing.

Instead, run the regex on the text of each `td` like below:

```
Matcher dateMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\/\\d+\\/\\d+").matcher("");

Document doc = ...
Elements tdElements = doc.select(...);

for(Element td : tdElements) {
    if (dateMatcher.reset(td.ownText()).matches()) {
        sb.append("1");
    }
}
```

Comment: by adding above code it is giving the following error...
"non-static variable dateMatcher cannot be referenced from a static context
----"

Comment: @AhmedTalha The whole above code should be used inside a method body.

Comment: sorry sorry... I was actually defining the Matcher outside the method.. Thank you so much Stephan it working man...